# Create RaisedButton slightly less that screen width

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a list of buttons on a Flutter page; I want the buttons to be big, but not flush to the left and right margins. Can someone show me how to do this?  I've tried tweaking every aspect of this that I can think of and perusing examples across the Internet, not all I can find is examples that go the full width, not most of the width.

Here's the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _createButton(idx: 1, btnText: 'Button 1', btnColor: Colors.red),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _createButton(
                  idx: 2, btnText: 'Button 2', btnColor: Colors.yellow),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _createButton(
                  idx: 3, btnText: 'Button 3', btnColor: Colors.green),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _createButton(
                idx: 0,
                btnText: 'Button 4',
                btnColor: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createButton(
      {int idx,
      String btnText,
      Color btnColor,
      Color textColor = Colors.black}) {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: btnColor,
      textColor: textColor,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Text(btnText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      onPressed: () {
        this.setStatus(idx);
      },
    );
  }

  void setStatus(idx) {
    print("Home: setStatus($idx)");
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give a little bit of space around your widgets (on each side customizably), then `Padding` is the widget you need:

Just wrap your `Column` in `Padding` and set its `padding` property to, for example, `const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16)` and you will have 16dp of space on the left and right of your `Column`.

[Padding class - widgets library - Dart API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside the a container and calcualte the width you want depending on the width property of the device

```dart
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.96 // 96% of the screen width,
    child:  _createButton(idx: 1, btnText: 'Button 1', btnColor: Colors.red),
)
```

or you can provide the margin named argument to the Container widget

```dart
Container(
    //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.96 // 96% of the screen width
    margin: const EdgetInsets.all(5),
    child:  _createButton(idx: 1, btnText: 'Button 1', btnColor: Colors.red),
)
```